# Not able to detect direction of forward and reverse

Tags: ios, swift

I have an `pageMenuController`, when ever i swipe right and left i need to detect the direction its moves.My delegate method is :

```
func pageMenuController(_ pageMenuController: PageMenuController, didScrollToPageAtIndex index: Int, direction: PageMenuNavigationDirection) {
        print(index)
        // The page view controller will begin scrolling to a new page.
    }
func pageMenuController(_ pageMenuController: PageMenuController, willScrollToPageAtIndex index: Int, direction: PageMenuNavigationDirection) {
}
func pageMenuController(_ pageMenuController: PageMenuController, scrollingProgress progress: CGFloat, direction: PageMenuNavigationDirection) {

    }
func pageMenuController(_ pageMenuController: PageMenuController, didSelectMenuItem index: Int, direction: PageMenuNavigationDirection) {
}
```

i am adding my code to detect the direct in `willScrollToPageAtIndex`.Like below :

```
func pageMenuController(_ pageMenuController: PageMenuController, willScrollToPageAtIndex index: Int, direction: PageMenuNavigationDirection) {
 print(index)
        print(PageMenuNavigationDirection.forward)
         print(PageMenuNavigationDirection.self)
        print(direction.hashValue)
        print(direction.rawValue)
         print(direction)
}
```

nothing values is printing like forward or reverse direction.And my `PageMenuNavigationDirection`class is like this :

```
import Foundation

@objc public enum PageMenuNavigationDirection: Int {

    /// Forward direction. Can be right in a horizontal orientation or down in a vertical orientation.
    case forward

    /// Reverse direction. Can be left in a horizontal orientation or up in a vertical orientation.
    case reverse
}

extension EMPageViewControllerNavigationDirection {

    var toPageMenuNavigationDirection: PageMenuNavigationDirection {
        switch self {
        case .forward:
            return .forward
        default:
            return .reverse
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea how can i get the directions when i swipe right and left side ?

Comment: What is a `pageMenuController`? Is it a `PageViewController`? Then which object is calling `willScrollToPageAtIndex`? I think you should add more code to help us to figure what you want.

Comment: Can you explain why willScrollToPageAtIndex would be called?

Comment: @Y.Bonafons sorry for an late replay. You can check this like https://github.com/tamanyan/SwiftPageMenu  . I am using for page menu swipe

Comment: @matt i am using this https://github.com/tamanyan/SwiftPageMenu for my page menu swipe.Here only i was not able to detect the diretions

Comment: Maybe you forgot to set the delegate of your `PageMenuController`? Something like `pageMenuController.delegate = self`